# PostgreSQL: Select random records satisfying limiting condition(s)

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

Lets say I have an Item table with item records, Each item can belong to one or more category. Each category has one or more items in them

How would I select a random list of **unique** items which will match the condition such as 5 items from category A, 3 items from Category B  , 4 items from Category C etc and also retaining the order of category i.e. A -> B -> C

The sort_order and per category item_count for the query is stored in another table.

The item table is fairly large ~1 million rows, the items satisfying the condition may have fairly large gaps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT item_id FROM (
    ((SELECT t.category,t.item_id from items t where t.category ='A' order by random() limit 5)
    UNION
    (SELECT t.category,t.item_id from items t where t.category ='B' order by random() limit 3)
    UNION
    (SELECT t.category,t.item_id from items t where t.category ='C' order by random() limit 4))
ORDER BY category
```

I can't promise you that will be fast, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to do this with a `join`, like this:

```
select i.*
from (select i.*, row_number() over (partition by category order by random()) as seqnum
      from items i
     ) i join
     (select 'A' as category, 5 as num union all
      select 'B' as category, 3 as num union all
      select 'C' as category, 4 as num 
     ) l
     on i.category = l.category
where i.seqnum <= l.num;
```

However, this does not solve the problem for *unique* items.  So, the same item could appear in the list more than once.  Assuming that there are ample items for this request, I would first select a random category for each item and follow the same logic:

```
select i.*
from (select i.itemid, min(category) as category,
             row_number() over (partition by min(category)
                                order by random()
                               ) as seqnum
      from items i
      group by i.itemid
     ) i join
     (select 'A' as category, 5 as num union all
      select 'B' as category, 3 as num union all
      select 'C' as category, 4 as num 
     ) l
     on i.category = l.category
where i.seqnum <= l.num;
```

The use of `min()` is sort of a hack to get one category per item.